# How do I get from Iterable<Future<MyType>> to Future<List<MyType>> in Dart

Tags: dart

I want to load multiple descriptions from an async-function one-by-one by using map:

```
  Future<List<Description>> loadDescriptions(List<String> questions) async {
    Iterable<Future<Description>> iterable =
        questions.map((question) async => (await loadDescription(question)));
    return iterable.toList();
  }
```

`.toList()` unfortunately doesn't work here. Is there a way to rewrite the code in dart so that I get `Future<List<Description>>` as output?

Comment: Consider [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/wait.html) if you don't need to wait for each one in sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the following should work:

```
Future<List<Description>> loadDescriptions(List<String> questions) async =>
    [for (final question in questions) await loadDescription(question)];
```

I should add that the behavior in this solution is that each `Future` will be `await` before the next in a sequence (also mentioned by @jamesdlin) which in some cases can be suboptimal.

Instead, we can `await` on all `Future`'s at the same time and let Dart fetch the results and then return the `List<Description>` if using [`Future.wait`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-async/Future/wait.html):

```
Future<List<Description>> loadDescriptions(List<String> questions) =>
    Future.wait(questions.map(loadDescription));
```